# Django regex url NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am bashing my head on this for a couple of hours now... I now silly. However, I don't know where the error is:

So I have the following urls.py where the last line should allow me to serve a ticket object through the following url (e.g.) ticket/2/:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^landing/$', views.landing, name='landing'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^ticket/(?P<pk>[0-9])+/$', views.ticket_detail, name='ticket_detail'),
]
```

then the view for the ticket detail is:

```
def ticket_detail(request, pk):

    ticket_id = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=pk)

    return render(
        request,
        'tickets/ticket_detail.html',
        context={'ticket': ticket_id, }
    )
```

However, for some reason I get the following error:
**django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

Can someone please help? I went through the DetailView class as well and refactored the view, however same issue. I think it might be a matter of url regex... I hate regex :)

Comment: You have either `reverse('detail', ...)` in your code or `{% url 'detail' ... %}` in your template. However the url pattern is named `ticket_detail`. If you have already updated your code/template, you might have to restart the server.

Comment: @Alasdair is correct. That's a keyword which appears in your template (we know this because it does not appear in your urls) A quick word search is all you need (don't forget to check other templates if you are extending or including!)

Comment: Thanks guys... simple server restart solved it... :D